# Tuple Unpacking - ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

Simple problem here. I just can't seem to get how to resolve it.

Basically, I have a dictionary with multiple tuples within that store stock data.

ex.

```
portfolio = [('25-Jan-2001', 43.5, 25, 'CAT', 92.45),
('25-Jan-2001', 42.8, 50, 'DD', 51.19),
('25-Jan-2001', 42.1, 75, 'EK', 34.87),
('25-Jan-2001', 37.58, 100, 'GM', 37.58)]
```

And I'm trying to unpack it and multiply the purchase price by the number of shares. Ultimately adding them together afterwards.

```
def total_purchase_price(portfolio):
    purdate, purprice, numshares, sym, curprice = portfolio
    totalprice = 0
    for i in portfolio: 
        totalprice = purprice[i] * numshares[i]
        print(totalprice)
    return
```

However, I'm getting a ValueError: need more than 4 values to unpack.

Is this because strings aren't integers?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The way you are unpacking, you are expecting your data structure to come in like this: `('25-Jan-2001', 43.5, 25, 'CAT', 92.45)`. This is not the case as you are providing a list of tuples.

Comment: also what do you think is the value of `i` in your for loop?

Comment: Also should you use `unpack` ? you can do it even with out that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`portfolio` is a list containing 4 tuples. This line of code:

```
purdate, purprice, numshares, sym, curprice = portfolio
```

is attempting to unpack that list into 5 variables, which fails because there are only four items in it. I suspect that you want code something mode like:

```
# iterate through the items in the portfolio
for item in portfolio:
    # for each item, unpack the tuple into its constituent parts
    purdate, purprice, numshares, sym, curprice = item
    # ...do some calculations on those values
```

Comment: Or more canonically, just unpack directly: `for purdate, purprice, numshares, sym, curprice in portfolio:`. It will even make the code run a little faster to boot, especially for certain built-in generator returning functions, e.g. `zip` and many functions generating `tuple`s in the `itertools` module, where not keeping a reference to the `tuple` in the Python code lets the generator repopulate the same `tuple` over and over without needing to return a new one each time.

Answer (score 1):

bgporter's response is good, and probably what you are looking for. Your original intent to unpack the tuples in to your own arrays is also achievable:

```
def total_purchase_price(portfolio):
    purdate, purprice, numshares, sym, curprice = zip(*portfolio)
    totalprice = 0
    for i in range(len(portfolio)):
        totalprice = purprice[i] * numshares[i]
        print(totalprice)
    return
```

Note the zip(*portfolio) essentially unpacks the portfolio columns, and the range(len(portfolio)) in the for loop to get the length correct.  Results:

```
1087.5
2140.0
3157.5
3758.0
```

I still prefer @bgporter for simplicity & readability, but this approach is workable.

For a model answer, I would do this:

```
def total_purchase_price(portfolio):
    def px(row):
        purdate, purprice, numshares, sym, curprice = row
        return purprice * numshares
    print sum(map(px, portfolio))
```

Comment: Nice -- I wouldn't have thought of this columnar approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sum you can use the *sum* function unpacking in the loop:

```
def total_purchase_price(portfolio):
    return sum(pp * sh for _, pp, sh, _, _ in portfolio)
```

Or using python3 with [*extended iterable unpacking*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
def total_purchase_price(portfolio):
    return sum(pp * sh for _, pp, sh, *_ in portfolio)
```

Or if you like functional,  you can use some operator methods with [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
from operator import mul, itemgetter
from itertools import starmap


def total_purchase_price(portfolio):
    return sum(starmap(mul, map(itemgetter(1,2), portfolio)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @bgporter and @F1Rumors!!

My answer to this:

```
def total_purchase_price(portfolio):
    totalprice = 0
    totalpurprice = 0
    for item in portfolio:
        purdate, purprice, numshares, sym, curprice = item
        totalprice += purprice * numshares
        totalpurprice = totalprice
    print(totalpurprice)
    return
```

I could probably trim it down using @F1Rumors' suggestion, but this'll do for now!